# Pandas Dataframe multiply with a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

Is there a way to multiply each element of a row of a dataframe by an element of the same row from a particular column of another dataframe.

For example, such that:

df1:

```
1 2 3
2 2 2
3 2 1
```

and df2:

```
x 1 b
z 2 c
x 4 a
```

results in

```
1  2  3
4  4  4
12 8  4
```

So basically such that `df1[i,:] * df2[i,j] = df3[i,:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the first df by the column of the second df

Assuming your column names are `0,1,2`

```
df1.mul(df2[1],0)
```

Output

```
    0  1  2
0   1  2  3
1   4  4  4
2  12  8  4
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get "KeyError: 1"

Comment: Like I said, it's assuming your column names are `0,1,2`  Just replace `1` with the column name from df2 you want to use

Comment: My mistake. '1' instead of 1 solved this error. 
But now I get a Dataframe with twice as many rows than it should and every element is = NaN

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
I have created a variable that allows you to select that which column of the second dataframe you want to multiply with the numbers in the first dataframe.

```
arr1 = np.array(df1) # df1 to array

which_df2col_to_multiply = 0  # select col from df2
arr2 = np.array(df2)[:, which_df2col_to_multiply ] # selected col to array

print(np.transpose(arr2*arr1))  # result
```

This is the output:

```
[[1 2 3]
[4 4 4]
[12 8 4]]
```

Comment: This approach won't work for dataframes of different shapes eg. 500x3 and 500x100 matrices, right?

Comment: But based on what you asked, you wanted to multiply a single column with another dataframe, in that case it doesn't matter.

Comment: The error I get ist "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (531,) (531,128)